# Is $K:=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & \Bbb C \\ 0 & \Bbb C\end{pmatrix} \leq M_2(\Bbb C)$ simple in $M_2(\Bbb C)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

We take the ring $R:=M_2(\Bbb C)$ and we regard it as a $R$-module over itself.

If we take its left $R$-module $K:=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & \Bbb C \\ 0 & \Bbb C\end{pmatrix} \leq M_2(\Bbb C)$, is it simple?

I tried it by definition, but I failed. Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a$ is a nonzero element of $K$, can you show that $Ra = K$?

Then if $M \subseteq K$ is a nonzero submodule, it contains some nonzero $a$, and $K = Ra \subseteq M$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think yes: $$R\alpha=\{ \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12}  \\ a_{21}  & a_{22}  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & x \\ 0 & y \end{pmatrix}: a_{ij}\in \Bbb C \} = \{ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & a_{11}x+a_{12}y  \\ 0 & a_{21}x+a_{22}y   \end{pmatrix} \}= \{ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & c  \\ 0 & d  \end{pmatrix} : c,d\in \Bbb C\}=K.$$

Comment: How does this help?

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: Perfect! Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{gae}[1]{\newcommand{#1}{\operatorname{#1}}}\gae{End}\gae{rk}$
Call $e_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and identify $R:=M_2(\Bbb C)=\End_{\Bbb C}(\Bbb C^2)$. Then $K=\{f\in R\,:\,e_1\in\ker f\}$ and the question is:

> Given $f\in K\setminus\{0\}$ and another map $g\in K$, does there exist a linear map $h\in R$ such that $h\circ f=g$?

And this is clearly the case. In fact, the relevant linear algebra result is the following:

> Let $T:V\to W$ and $S:V\to Z$ be linear maps of $k$-vector spaces. There is a linear map $H:W\to Z$ such that $HT=S$ if and only if $\ker S\supseteq \ker T$ and $\rk T\ge\rk S$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By rk you mean the rank I guess. Also, could you please apply it on our case?

Comment: Yes, rank. In this case $V=W=Z=\Bbb C^2$, and it is just a matter of verifying that $T=f$ and $S=g$ satisfy those two conditions.